# Remove values before a particular value in dataframe column using regex using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

Remove values before a particular value in dataframe column  using regex using python
have a df with values :

df1

```
a         b        
tom      score:abc132
luke     score:123      
mark     score:132
mark     score:132
luke     value:123
tom      value:145
luke     score:123
tom      marrks:145
```

how to remove values before `:` in all the b column using regex.

expected output:

```
a         b        
tom      abc132
luke     123      
mark     132
mark     132
luke     123
tom      145
luke     123
tom      145
```

Comment: why not use `str.split` ? `df['b'].str.split(':',expand=True)[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].str.extract('\:(.*)$')[0]
```

Output:

```
      a       b
0   tom  abc132
1  luke     123
2  mark     132
3  mark     132
4  luke     123
5   tom     145
6  luke     123
7   tom     145
```